# Code working in Chrome and Edge but not in IE - setimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following downloadZip.html. The download works in Chrome and Edge, but not in IE. This file gets called as below from jspf page. When I click "Download listed documents" it call popupDownloadWindow(), which will open downloadZip.html in plainview. This html when loaded calls enableLink() and the flow goes. As the view is plainview, only first if block of enableLink() is executed (if(callerview == "plainview")). Not sure if this is happening because of setTimeout(). Please help me here. Let me know for any information.

```
function checkReturn(){
    //alert('checkReturn - sessionsNotOk global var = '+sessionsNotOk);
    if (sessionsNotOk != "DEF") {

        var docbases = sessionsNotOk.split(",");
        //alert('checkReturn - docbases arr = '+docbases+', length='+docbases.length);
        if (docbases.length == 1 && docbases[0] == "OK"){
            // All sessions are faja
            document.getElementById('divIndicator').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('checkSession').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('noSession').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.textAlign='center';
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.display='';

        } else {
                // We need to show the sublogin dialog
                var nextDocbase = docbases[0];

                //alert("Next NOT AVAILABLE session = "+nextDocbase);
                window.opener.$('#subloginmessage').css('display','none');
                window.opener.$('#loginIndicator').css('display','none');
                window.opener.$('#sub-uid').val(window.opener.$('#user_name').text());
                window.opener.$('#sub-uid').attr('disabled','disabled');
                window.opener.$('#sub_docbase').text(nextDocbase);

                document.getElementById('checkSession').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('noSession').style.display='inline';
                document.getElementById('noSession').style.textAlign='center';
                document.getElementById('noSession').style.display='';

                window.opener.sublogin_fw = "download";
                window.opener.sublogin_db = nextDocbase;

                window.opener.$('#sublogindialog').dialog('open');
                window.opener.$('#sublogindialog').dialog('option','title','Login to docbase: ' + nextDocbase + ' and click on Download listed documents link again!');
        }
        return;
    }
    //Check again in 0.5 second
    setTimeout("checkReturn()",500);
    //setTimeout(function() {
    //  checkReturn();
    //}, 500);

}
```

---

Complete code:

```
<script>
    var downloadZipChildWindow; 

    function popupDownloadWindow(){
        downloadZipChildWindow = window.open('../html/downloadZip.html?view=plainview','downloadwindow','width=300,height=200,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=no');
    }
</script>

<a id='download_link' class='download_link' href="#" onClick="popupDownloadWindow()">Download listed documents</a>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Download documents as Zip file</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        p
        {
            font-family:"Verdana";
            font-size:small;
        }
        a
        {
            font-family:"Helvetica";
            font-size:small;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var lastParam;
var sessionsNotOk = "DEF";
var callerView;

function getParam( paramName )
{
    paramName = paramName.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+paramName+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}

/*
 * Checks the return from ajax servlet call "../downloadzip?ask=isSRPsessionsOK&packageIDs="+pIDs".
 * Called always right after checkDocbaseSessions() call.
 */
function checkReturn(){
    //alert('checkReturn - sessionsNotOk global var = '+sessionsNotOk);
    if (sessionsNotOk != "DEF") {

        var docbases = sessionsNotOk.split(",");
        //alert('checkReturn - docbases arr = '+docbases+', length='+docbases.length);
        if (docbases.length == 1 && docbases[0] == "OK"){
            // All sessions are faja
            document.getElementById('divIndicator').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('checkSession').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('noSession').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.textAlign='center';
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.display='';

        } else {
                // We need to show the sublogin dialog
                var nextDocbase = docbases[0];

                //alert("Next NOT AVAILABLE session = "+nextDocbase);
                window.opener.$('#subloginmessage').css('display','none');
                window.opener.$('#loginIndicator').css('display','none');
                window.opener.$('#sub-uid').val(window.opener.$('#user_name').text());
                window.opener.$('#sub-uid').attr('disabled','disabled');
                window.opener.$('#sub_docbase').text(nextDocbase);

                document.getElementById('checkSession').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('noSession').style.display='inline';
                document.getElementById('noSession').style.textAlign='center';
                document.getElementById('noSession').style.display='';

                window.opener.sublogin_fw = "download";
                window.opener.sublogin_db = nextDocbase;

                window.opener.$('#sublogindialog').dialog('open');
                window.opener.$('#sublogindialog').dialog('option','title','Login to docbase: ' + nextDocbase + ' and click on Download listed documents link again!');
        }
        return;
    }
    //Check again in 0.5 second
    //setTimeout("checkReturn()",500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        checkReturn();
    }, 500);
}

function enableLink(){
    callerView = getParam("view");
    var pkgType = "";
    var params = "";
    var packageIDs = "";

    if (callerView == "plainview") {

        pkgType = window.opener.$('#hiddenPkgType').attr('value');
        // Check available sessions
        if (pkgType == 'srp'){
            document.getElementById('dlink').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('checkSession').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('checkSession').style.textAlign='center';
            document.getElementById('checkSession').style.display='';
            packageIDs = window.opener.$('#hiddenSRPIDs').attr('value');
            checkDocbaseSessions(packageIDs);
            checkReturn();
        }
        params = window.opener.$('#hiddenDownloadParams').attr('value');

    } else if (callerView == "packagedetailview") {

        pkgType = window.opener.$('#hiddenPkgType_DetailedPackageView').attr('value');
        if (pkgType == "" || pkgType == null) {
            alert("Still loading data, window will be closed. Please click on download button after all data have been loaded on the page!");
            window.close();
        }
        params = window.opener.$('#hiddenDownloadParams_DetailedPackageView').attr('value');

    } else if (callerView == "SRP_packagedetailview") {

        // Prepare/check remote sessions
        packageIDs = window.opener.$('#SRP_DPV_pkgIDs').attr('value');
        checkDocbaseSessions(packageIDs);
        checkReturn();

        pkgType = 'srp';
        if (pkgType == "" || pkgType == null) {
            alert("Still loading data, window will be closed. Please click on download button after all data have been loaded on the page!");
            window.close();
        }
        params = window.opener.$('#hiddenDownloadParams_SRP_DetailedPackageView').attr('value');

    } else if (callerView == "SRP_checkstatusview") {

        // Prepare/check remote sessions
        packageIDs = window.opener.$('#SRP_CSV_pkgIDs').attr('value');
        checkDocbaseSessions(packageIDs);
        checkReturn();

        pkgType = 'srp';
        if (pkgType == "" || pkgType == null) {
            alert("Still loading data, window will be closed. Please click on download button after all data have been loaded on the page!");
            window.close();
        }
        params = window.opener.$('#hiddenDownloadParams_SRP_CheckStatusView').attr('value');

    }

    if (pkgType == 'nlp' || pkgType == 'monnlp') {
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_country').style.display='inline';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_product').style.display='inline';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_country').style.textAlign='center';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_product').style.textAlign='center';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames').style.display='none';                                      
    } else if (pkgType == 'clp') {
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_country').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_product').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames').style.display='inline';    
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames').style.textAlign='center';
    } else if (pkgType == 'ipl') {
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_country').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_product').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames').style.display='inline';    
        document.getElementById('download_zip_stdfilenames').style.textAlign='center';
    }

    //Defined as global
    zipParamsImp = params + "&filename=import";
    zipParamsStd = params + "&filename=standard";
}

function showIndicator(param){
    document.getElementById('divIndicator').style.display='inline';
    document.getElementById('divIndicator').style.textAlign='center';
    document.getElementById('divIndicator').style.display='';
    document.getElementById('dlink').style.display='none';

    var parameters = "";
    if (param == 'import'){
        parameters = zipParamsImp;
    } else if (param == 'standard') {
        parameters = zipParamsStd;
    } else if (param == 'standard_nlp_country') {
        parameters = zipParamsStd + "_nlp_country";
    } else if (param == 'standard_nlp_product') {
        parameters = zipParamsStd + "_nlp_product";
    }
    lastParam = param;  
    postwith("../downloadzip",parameters);
}

function postwith (to, params) {
    var myForm = window.opener.document.createElement("form");
    myForm.method="post" ;
    myForm.action = to ;
    myForm.style.display = 'none';

    jQuery.each(params.split('&'), function(){
        var pair = this.split('=');
        var myInput = window.opener.document.createElement("input") ;
        myInput.setAttribute("name", pair[0]) ;
        myInput.setAttribute("value", pair[1]);
        myForm.appendChild(myInput);
    });
    var lastInput = window.opener.document.createElement("input") ;
    lastInput.setAttribute("name", "download_token_value_id") ;
    lastInput.setAttribute("value", "");
    myForm.appendChild(lastInput);

    window.opener.document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
    myForm.submit();
    window.opener.document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;

    //setTimeout("checkProgress()",1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        checkProgress();
    },1000);
}

/*
 * Checks return from servlet call "../downloadzip?ask=isready" -> ask whether DownloadAsZipServlet
 * has finished its work or not. If finished, close this popup.
 */
function checkProgress(){
    window.focus();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../downloadzip?ask=isready",
        dataType: "text",
        //dataType: "script",
        //timeout: 2000,
        success: function(results)
        {   
            // Normal flow
            //var result = eval('('+results+')');
            var currParams = window.opener.$('#hiddenDownloadParams').attr('value');
            //After closing DPV and clicking on Download Listed Documents button, we have to remove caller param, because there is no caller.
            //Caller exists only if openPackage function called, and Download is on a DPV page.
            //If we do not remove caller param, then exception occurs.

            var callerPrefix = currParams.substring(0,currParams.indexOf('&'));
            if (callerPrefix.indexOf('caller=') > -1) {
                window.opener.$('#hiddenDownloadParams').attr('value',currParams.replace(callerPrefix+'&',""));
            } else {
                // No caller param found
            }

            if (results.indexOf('window.close()') > -1) {
                window.close();
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            window.top.document.location.href = "../jsp/logout.jsp?msg=Application error (HTTPREQ quicksearch download documents). You have been logged out!";
        }
    });
}

 /*
  * In case of SRP - checks whether sessions for all required docbases are available.
  * It is needed, because SRP package documents can be located in different docbases.
  */
function checkDocbaseSessions(pIDs){
    sessionsNotOk = "DEF";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../downloadzip?ask=isSRPsessionsOK&packageIDs="+pIDs,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(results)
        {   
            //alert(results);
            if ($.trim(results) == 'OK'){
                //alert("Sessions are OK!");
                sessionsNotOk="OK";
            } else {
                sessionsNotOk=results;
                //alert("Sessions are NOT OK! - "+sessionsNotOk);

            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            window.top.document.location.href = "../jsp/logout.jsp?msg=Application error (HTTPREQ quicksearch download documents). You have been logged out!";
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica; font-size: x-small;" onload="enableLink();">
    <div id="divIndicator" style="display: none"><br />
        <p>Zip file creation in progress. This may take a few minutes, please wait and do not navigate away or start another query!</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="qIndicator"> <img border="0" src="../img/indicator.gif"></span>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: center">Download listed documents</p>
    <div id="dlink" style="text-align: center">
        <a href="#" style="text-align: center" id='download_zip_impfilenames' onClick="showIndicator('import')">With import file names</a> 
        <br />
        <a href="#" style="text-align: center" id='download_zip_stdfilenames' onClick="showIndicator('standard')">With standard file names</a>
        <a href="#" style="display: none; text-align: center" id='download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_country' onClick="showIndicator('standard_nlp_country')">With standard file names starting with country</a>
        <a href="#" style="display: none; text-align: center" id='download_zip_stdfilenames_nlp_product' onClick="showIndicator('standard_nlp_product')">With standard file names starting with product</a>
    </div>
    <div id="noSession" style="display: none">
    <p>Some required sessions are unavailable. Please login to the docbase!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="checkSession" style="display: none">
    <p>Checking required sessions in progress. Please wait...</p>
    <br />
    <span id="qIndicator"> <img border="0" src="../img/indicator.gif"></span>
    <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to go through the entire code ?

Comment: Sorry, not able to figure out what is the issue, enableLink first if block is called because of plainview, and the inner if, so checkDocbaseSessions(), checkReturn().

Comment: whats the security settings on IE? Is your website restricted?

Comment: Unrelated, but `setTimeout(checkReturn, 500)` is sufficient. The most reliable way to access variables across parent/child windows is to use the child window handle (parent accessing child variable) or `window.opener` (child accessing parent). A single check is not sufficient because it may take longer than 0.5s to open a window and execute its code. This assumes the same domain.

Comment: running on localhost, I tried setTimeout(checkReturn, 500); setTimeout(function() { checkReturn(); }, 500); didn't work in IE.